# How can I use tee to print the input stream?

Tags: pipe, process-substitution

I have a pipe line that looks like this:

```
cat myfile | awk '$3 > 0 { print $1, $2 * $3 }' | tee >(printf) | perl myscript.pl
```

I would like to print the input to my Perl script using `tee`. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it OK for tee's output to appear on stderr? If tee's output must come on stdout, does it matter whether it appears before or after any output that the perl script might produce?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to print the results of tee to stdout and have it appear before the results of my perl script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is that when `tee` is invoked in the pipeline, its stdout has already been aimed at `perl`'s stdin. The only way for it to know where stdout was aimed before the pipeline started is for you to dup stdout to another file descriptor, and to access that file descriptor via `/dev/fd/n`, if your OS supports that. So, this may be an option:

```
# dup fd 1 to another fd for the duration of this shell script.
# we'll use 4. any number higher than 2 is probably OK, but
# some coordination is required if a containing shell script
# decided to do the same thing.
exec 4>&1
cat myfile | awk '$3 > 0 { print $1, $2 * $3 }' | tee /dev/fd/4 | perl myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it printed to the terminal, then use `/dev/tty`.  For more, see the manpage [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html).